# How can I account for large lag cycles in timeseries regression with ARIMA errors?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima, modeling

I'm trying to create a model and generate a forecast of energy consumption in an HVAC system at the university I attend. I have energy consumption for the system and some basic weather data. Sample of the data below:

```
# A tsibble: 6 x 13 [30m] <UTC>
# Key:       equipment [1]
  totalHeat.AHU fanEnergy time                equipment totalHeat.room totalHeat totalEnergy humidityAvg tempAvg pressureMax stationID
          <dbl>     <dbl> <dttm>              <chr>              <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>       <int>   <int>       <dbl> <chr>    
1        74.3      27.1   2020-07-24 15:00:00 AHU2E             11.2      85.5        113.            84      28       1022. KVACHARL~
2         0.179     0.691 2020-07-25 02:30:00 AHU2E              0.618     0.796        1.49          NA      NA         NA  NA       
3         0.163     0.691 2020-07-25 03:00:00 AHU2E              0.629     0.792        1.48          99      22       1022. KVACHARL~
4         0.150     0.691 2020-07-25 03:30:00 AHU2E              0.638     0.788        1.48          99      22       1022. KVACHARL~
5         0.138     0.691 2020-07-25 04:00:00 AHU2E              0.621     0.759        1.45          99      21       1022. KVACHARL~
6         0.126     0.691 2020-07-25 04:30:00 AHU2E              0.616     0.742        1.43          99      21       1021. KVACHARL~
```

Variable of interest, totalEnergy, is generated by two units and has a daily cycle which looks like this over the course of a week:

[image: Plot showing daily cycle of energy use on a weekly basis]
[image: plot of totalEnergy with acf and pacf]

[image: plot of differences, acf, and pcf showing significant lags up to 30 time periods]

I've tried to create a regression with ARIMA errors to model the energy consumption found in totalEnergy using the following code:

```
fit = weather_energy %>% 
  filter(equipment == "AHU2E") %>%
  fill_gaps() %>%
  model(ARIMA(totalEnergy ~ tempAvg + tempSq))
```

Where I'm trying to model totalEnergy as a quadratic function of temperature with ARIMA errors, looking at a weekly season plot of the residuals, it looks like the model isn't able to capture the day/night cycle of energy use as residuals jump significantly every day. Weekly seasonal plot of the residuals:

[image: Weekly seasonal plot of residuals]

I thought that adding a binary indicator variable as to whether the HVAC system is in an active state would help account for this discrepancy so I coded that into the data and created another model.

```
fit = weather_energy %>% 
  filter(equipment == "AHU2E") %>%
  fill_gaps() %>%
  model(ARIMA(totalEnergy ~ tempAvg + tempSq + activeHours))
```

[image: Weekly seasonal plot of residuals of second model]

This model seems to perform a lot better, but the residuals still show a distinct daily pattern.

[image: gg residual plot showing normally distributed residuals and significant acfs]

It doesn't seem like this approach is enough to account for the cycles in this data, but given the regularity of the cycle, it seems to me that there should be SOME way to capture it in a model. Is there a way to inform the model of the 48 period (daily) lag at which the data cycles? Or to deal with the long "downtimes" between cycles? Or just another model which might be better suited to this type of cyclical data?

Thanks!

Comment: 0. Welcome to CV.SE. 1. Have you consider defining a seasonality of 48 like `ts(data,start=mydate, frequency=48)`?

Comment: @usεr11852 Thank you! Informing the model of the 48 period seasonality helped a lot. I was able to implement this approach using auto.arima on a univariate ts of the target variable but for my purposes using `fable::ARIMA(totalEnergy ~ PDQ(period=48))`  worked better with my workflow and without the need for a ts object.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: As mentioned in the comments, my original `NNETAR()` model:

1. Isn't very good
2. Is so large and inefficient that forecasting on ay reasonable timescale is impossible on my machine

Using the suggestion of informing the model of the 48 period seasonality I was able to generate the following:

```
dynRegTrain <- data %>% 
  filter(time < dmy_h("1-04-2021 00")) %>%
  model(ARIMA(totalEnergy ~ tempAvg + I(tempAvg^2) + PDQ(period=48)))
```

[image: gg_residuals plot]
[image: forecasts of dynamic regression ARIMA model compared to actual data]

I think there's still additional variance that could be capture, but this is pretty good for now. See [here](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/longseasonality/) for another approach.

---

**Original Answer**

I was able to make use of the `NNETAR()` function from the fable package along with some scaling functions to constrain the forecasts to a reasonable range.

```
scaled_logit <- function(x, lower = 0, upper = 200) {
  log((x - lower) / (upper - x))
}
inv_scaled_logit <- function(x, lower = 0, upper = 200) {
  (upper - lower) * exp(x) / (1 + exp(x)) + lower
}
my_scaled_logit <- new_transformation(
                    scaled_logit, inv_scaled_logit)
fit5 <- data %>%
  model(
    NNETAR(
      my_scaled_logit(totalEnergy)
    )
  )
```

For some reason the `ARIMA` function would not create a model with large lags, but this function returned a NNAR(41, 1, 21)[2] model which seems to have sufficiently described the data.

[image: seasonal plot of residuals with a weekly period]
[image: residuals plot showing lags and normally distributed residuals]

The forecast of the data appears much more reasonable than previous methods as well.

[image: autoplot of predictions]

Comment: In fairness this model doesn't seem to be exceptionally strong for how large it seems to be (41 AR terms with 21 neurons, a bit excessive...). Why not do something like a GAM with correlated errors? (e.g. something like `gamm(totalEnergy ~ s(tempAvg) + s(tempSq) + activeHours + s(time_of_day), correlation = corARMA(form = ~ 1|Day, p = 1))`? There is pretty stable pattern within each day. (A GAM is pretty much what `prophet` will fit.)